# Android Chromium Build fail with NDK Library Load

Tags: android, browser, chromium

Whenever we trying to build Chromium in android studio that time its fail to load NDK library.

**Error logs are here :**

org.chromium.base.library_loader.ProcessInitException: errorCode=4
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.AsyncInitializationActivity.onStartupFailure(AsyncInitializationActivity.java:286)
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.NativeInitializationController$1.onFailure(NativeInitializationController.java:101)
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.AsyncInitTaskRunner.tasksPossiblyComplete(AsyncInitTaskRunner.java:182)
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.AsyncInitTaskRunner.lambda$null$0$AsyncInitTaskRunner(AsyncInitTaskRunner.java:127)
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.-$$Lambda$AsyncInitTaskRunner$cJc0Kjib2rp_haGN4uefBvQ1s58.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: org.chromium.base.library_loader.ProcessInitException: errorCode=2
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadMainDexAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:662)
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.ensureMainDexInitialized(LibraryLoader.java:456)
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.ensureInitialized(LibraryLoader.java:440)
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.AsyncInitTaskRunner.loadNativeLibrary(AsyncInitTaskRunner.java:138)
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.AsyncInitTaskRunner.lambda$startBackgroundTasks$1$AsyncInitTaskRunner(AsyncInitTaskRunner.java:126)
at org.chromium.chrome.browser.init.-$$Lambda$AsyncInitTaskRunner$xIQXLdsNGYGpypXLZkBvhfVEoSo.run(Unknown Source:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.chromium.chrome-3FZb2O0sMrWWCQ2kNEh8Og==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.chromium.chrome-3FZb2O0sMrWWCQ2kNEh8Og==/lib/arm, /data/app/org.chromium.chrome-3FZb2O0sMrWWCQ2kNEh8Og==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libc++_chrome.cr.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1067)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadWithSystemLinkerAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:617)
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadMainDexAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:653)

Please review this and share solution if you have any thank you.

Comment: Could you please describe the way you're trying to build?

Comment: We have followed steps to get chromium official repository code as below  

Step 1 

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_build_instructions.md#Installing-and-Running-Chromium-on-a-device/ 

Step 2 

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/android_studio.md 
Step 3  

Command for Split Chromium Gradle file in Android Studio.

Comment: You should use ninja build system as described here https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/android_build_instructions.md#build-chromium It won't build using Gradle as the majority of Android projects